# Doors unlocking themselves after being locked for hours. Mitsubishi Verada

Tags: mitsubishi

doors are unlocking after hours of car being locked up.  Mitsubishi Verada.

Comment: What year is your car? Have you done any work to the electrical system lately (like changed the battery)? I take it has a key fob associated with it? More than likely this is an issue with the Body Control Module (BCM). You may try disconnecting the battery for a 1/2 hour to reset all of the electronics.

Answer (score 1):

Some cars with electronic locks unlock themselves as a precaution when they detect that the battery power is getting low.  This is to try to prevent the situation where the battery is completely flat but the doors remain locked.

It may be that your battery is past its best or it may be that the system that checks the remaining power in the battery has developed a fault.

Comment: Have a specific car in mind, or link to documentation on same?

Comment: I know that there was a Watchdog article on Saab cars doing this some years ago.  I suspect many manufacturers use similar base modules for control of items such as central locking so it's conceivable that this is being caused by a similar problem.